# Is there any Deactivate/ Remove button for company owner in careers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I've added a company page in Stackoverflow careers and now I'm regret and decided to remove it.

I've searched a lot but I couldn't find any "Deactivate" or "Hide from public" button. Is there a way to remove/deactivate/unpublish my company page from stackoverflow careers ?
I have tested this feature again and I couldn't find any Unpublish button.
Why I can't see this feature?
[image]

Answer (score 20):

**Yes!**

To deactivate your Company Page:

1. Log into your employer portal.
2. Click the "Company Pages" link in the top menu.
3. If you aren't redirected to your Company Page, find your Company Page on the Company Page overview page.
4. Select the "Settings" tab.
5. You should see a "Status" area there telling you the page's status, when it was published, and last edited. Underneath that is an "Unpublish" option. Here's an image for reference:

[image: Option to unpublish your Company Page]

This will only unpublish or deactivate your Company Page. You can always re-publish again. If you have further questions, please email our Support team at careers@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: There is no Unpublish button could you please respond?

Comment: cant find unpublish button again