# "Unpublish" button for company page not present

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314604/2101822) a few months ago and I got [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314619/2101822). **But The Answer Is Not Working for me** and unfortunately I can't see any Unpublish button in my dashboard again. Here is a screenshot of the page:

[image]

As you see there is **no Unpublish button**. why this feature is not available for me. Is that a bug on Stackoverflow Careers

Comment: @Magisch I explained that the answer is not working for me. I also attached the picture of it.

Comment: So update your original question. Don't open a new one. It may also be wise to contact SE directly via the [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link

Comment: I have already done that. but I guess It can be a bug and this feature is not available just for me

Comment: Mhm. Fair enough then.

Answer (score -2):

It's not a bug. Only the owner of a company page can unpublish it, regardless of you being an admin on the account. Your screenshot indicates this is the situation.

To unpublish the page, you'd have to click the change owner link next to the listed owner and then transfer if into your name. Then the unpublish button should appear.

Or if the owner is no longer available or you are not an admin, you can email us at careers@stackoverflow.com and we'll take care of it.

Comment: So was the [previous dev](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314604/is-there-any-deactivate-remove-button-for-company-owner-in-careers/314619#314619) wrong?  Was that a dev only button?

Comment: They are partially correct. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is so odd because I want to delete the company page with the same user I have created that page. how is that possible?